# Swift: UIWebView in PlayGround not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift-playground

My Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
//import PlaygroundSupport
import XCPlayground

let url = URL(string: "https://github.com")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)

let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200.0, height: 1200.0))
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

But I see empty white frame, without content from github. I have no idea :-(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the Playground to make the live view the webview as below:

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit
    import PlaygroundSupport

    let url = URL(string: "https://github.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200.0, height: 1200.0))
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = webView
```

Also UIWebview is old (since iOS 2) and super buggy.  Consider [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) (new in iOS 8) unless you really require UIWebView.

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit
    import PlaygroundSupport

    let url = URL(string: "https://github.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200.0, height: 1200.0))
    webView.load(request)
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = webView
```

Comment: thanks, but you solution show not the content from github :-(

Comment: it shows on xcode 8.  did you open the assistant editor? Option+Command+Return

Comment: yes, now I see result after playground restart, you save my day